# Wordpress table not being created when CREATE TABLE SQL command is executed

Tags: sql, wordpress

I am building a wordpress plugin which, when a function is called, will create a table in the database.

I have the following code:

```
        function student_custom_data()
    {
        
        #create custom table if not exist
        
        $sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Wick_Custom_Student_Data) (
            id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            user_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
            target INT(6) NOT NULL,
            sen VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
            disAd VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        )"; }
```

When the function is called the table does not get created. There is no table called `Wick_Custom_Student_Data` already existing in the database.

Why is the database table not being created?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I realise that for wordpress I needed to get and set the charset_collate property to the create table statement and use dbDelta to execute the SQL properly:

```
        global $wpdb;
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
        
        $sql ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Wick_Custom_Student_Data (
            id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            user_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
            target INT(6) NOT NULL,
            sen VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
            disAd VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
        
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
```